# Segmentation fault: 11when using if condition

Tags: c

I keep getting the error `Segmentation fault` at the if condition. I thought it was because I was not using `strcpy` command but that also gives the same error.

Equipment will be assigned numerous strings over time which will be less than <100 characters everytime. 
What is it that I am missing?

```
char *aircraft, *aircraft_array[60000], equipment[100];
int size=0;


aircraft=strtok(equipment," ");


while (aircraft!=NULL){

            aircraft_array[size]=aircraft;
            size++;

            if (strcmp(aircraft_array[size],aircraft)==0){
                printf("%s\n",aircraft);
            }


            aircraft=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(aircraft_array[size],aircraft)==0){` in the previous statement you incremented size. `aircraft_array[size]`  now contains an uninitialised pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the variable size was incremented before the if statement instead of to be incremented after the if statement

```
        size++;
        ^^^^^^^
        if (strcmp(aircraft_array[size],aircraft)==0){
                                  ^^^^^
```

Exchange the statements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the return value from strtok is not persistent, the pointer refers to an internal static buffer which gets modified every time you call strtok(NULL, " ");

What you need to do is to allocate space for the token and then copy the string to that space e.g.

```
aircraft=strtok(equipment," ");

while (aircraft!=NULL)
{
  aircraft_array[size]=malloc(strlen(aircraft)+1);
  strcpy(aircraft_array[size], aircraft);
  size++;
```